# Getting most recent instance of each category in a queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a model 'Thing' with these fields:

```
name: TextField
category: TextField
date: DateField
```

I first do an icontains query on name:

```
Thing.objects.filter(name__icontaints='substring')
```

My question is how to filter that result to only give the most recent item in each category.

If I get three results with a category of 'widget' I only want one widget in the result set - the most recent one.

My naive solution would be to iterate through the queryset, keep a record of most recent dates and construct a new result set. Is there a better way? One that preferably works at the database level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this reliably across all databases since the queries vary quite a bit.

With MySQL you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    name,
    category,
    date
FROM
    thing
WHERE
    name LIKE '%substring%'
GROUP BY date
```

With PostgreSQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (category)
    name,
    category,
    date
FROM
    thing
WHERE
    name LIKE '%substring%'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

If you are using PostgreSQL, than you can use this patch to get `DISTINCT ON` support: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6422

Comment: Thanks for that. However I'm reluctant to start using raw SQL let alone db-specific SQL. I was hoping there would some clever trick with aggregates or an EXTRA clause. Hmmmmmm. I think I might precalculate the most recent as writes only happen in batches.